# How do I read the temperatures from two (or more) USB thermometers?

Tags: usb

I have two identical USB thermometers connected to one computer. If I run lsusb, I get:

```
lsusb -d 0c45:
Bus 004 Device 010: ID 0c45:7401 Microdia TEMPer Temperature Sensor
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0c45:7401 Microdia TEMPer Temperature Sensor
```

Bus 004 Device 010 is the one outside my house.
Bus 003 Device 004 is the one inside my house.

How do I read the outside temperature only?

I automatically assume that the same procedure can be used for reading the inside temperature.

Comment: Everything I find on the Internet keeps referring to /dev/ttyUSBx  
I have no such thing. I only have tty through tty63, and ttyS0 through ttyS31. There is also ttyprintk, but no ttyUSB.
Should there be? Am I missing something?

Comment: When I run lsusb -t it looks like the thermometers show up as Human Interface Devices. Does this matter?

Comment: Still no ttyUSBx. When I run `dmesg | grep input`, the thermometers show up as  `[11172.798870] input: RDing TEMPerV1.4 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/0003:0C45:7401.0035/input/input39`    
`[11172.853145] hid-generic 0003:0C45:7401.0035: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [RDing TEMPerV1.4] on usb-0000:00:02.0-3/input0` and  `[11172.859372] hid-generic 0003:0C45:7401.0036: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [RDing TEMPerV1.4] on usb-0000:00:02.0-3/input1`
 Is it possible to access them using this information in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm marking the thread as solved, although it's only sort of solved. I still haven't found out how to connect to the thermometers through something like /dev/ttyUSB0. I have no ttyUSBx at all. Removing brltty didn't make any difference at all.

What I did was to install [Temperusb 1.5.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/temperusb/1.5.3) which scans for all thermometers and gives me their values. It identifies the thermometers differently. It looks for them in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/` instead of `/dev/ttyx` . Anyway, it works and I think I can learn a few things by studying the source code (it's written in Python).

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried those, but after a quick look around the web, it seems you need to install software to interact with the device: http://dev-random.net/temperature-measuring-using-linux-and-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Yes, I need software to access them (e.g. TEMPer or digitemp ) but I don't know how to access a specific one of the two. Like how do I read the outside temperature only. I can easily read the temperature if I have only one thermometer connected and I could scan for all thermometers, but then they don't necessarily show up in the same order every time.